# How do I prevent AWS Infrastructure contractor from seeing our application code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2

We have a web app on an EC2 instance and we brought in a contractor to setup our AWS environment for us. He has developed a Terraform script I can run to launch a VPC with public/private subnets, load balancers, etc. At the moment the EC2 web app doesn’t contain the code we want to protect (ie not have stolen/copied). How can I set things up in IAM so that the contractor can still help us troubleshoot our environment after we’ve launched it, but without him having access to the code we will put on the EC2 instance?

Comment: Ask your lawyer to draft proper contracts. Restricting the developers / contractors will often only cause frustration and reduce the work efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Preventing access to the EC2 instances via SSH, S3 buckets where the code resides, and the software repository itself should prevent unauthorized access.

Grant only privileges needed to develop the infrastructure in a development account, with a hello world type app used to baseline software dependencies and installation. Do not promote any software that is sensitive to this environment.

When promoting infrastructure changes to production or staging, insurance the contractor has limited permission in these environments. Ideally only you and trusted employees would have full access to these accounts. The contractor should provide code and documentation to allow you to run infrastructure scripts with elevated privileges in production.

Consider granting the contractor a limited production IAM policy, such as Security Auditor that grants read only access to key resources.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways this can be done,
One such method is not providing physical access and only providing relevant details through DevOps tools.

You can have ci/cd pipeline and log aggregation which will help him provide support, but these all require upfront cost and setting up such infrastructure.